# How can I know if a process is running background or foreground in "ps" or "ps -ef" command output?

Tags: linux, ps, background-process

How can I know if a process is running background or foreground in commands `ps` or `ps -ef`?

I first thought that when I type in `ps -ef`, there is a section named TTY.
when I look into the list of TTY, most of them are `?`. I wonder if that question mark means process running background.

I want to check if I am right! If not, I want to know how I can know if the process is running background or foreground?

ps. command `jobs` is not used here.

Answer (score 6):

The `stat` field [has an extra `+` for foreground processes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#PROCESS_STATE_CODES):

```
ps -e -o pid,tty,stat,cmd
```

Foreground processes are those whose process group id (`pgid`) is the foreground one on the terminal (`tpgid`):

```
ps -e -o pid,pgid,tpgid,tty,cmd | awk '$2==$3'
```

> when I look into the list of TTY, most of them are '?' (question marks)
>   I wonder if that question mark means process running background

No, that means that they have no controlling tty (daemons or kernel threads, neither foreground nor background). For a list of *background* proceses:

```
ps -e -o pid,pgid,tpgid,tty,cmd | awk '$3!=-1 && $2!=$3'
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***The OP asked, "... how I can know if the process is running background or foreground?"***

The foreground and background status of a *process* are reported by `ps` as the **state** of the process. `man ps` lists these *process states* under the heading of `PROCESS STATE CODE`.

`ps -ef` doesn't report process state, but referring to `man ps` we find in the `OUTPUT FORMAT CONTROL` section that the `-o` argument may be used to specify the output of `ps` via one or more *keywords*. These *keywords* are listed in the `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` section, and with extraordinary persistence one will eventually find the `s`, `stat` and `state` keywords listed. But note that while all three of these *keywords* will provide **state** in the output, only the `stat` *keyword* will give the `multi-character process state`! The take-away: **`ps` favors the diligent user**.

As an example, the following `ps` command will output the **PID**, the **state**, and the **command** that started the process using the *keywords* `pid`, `stat` and `command`:

```
ps -eo pid,stat,command
```

To see how this works, consider this example:

In one terminal, run this command:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 > /dev/null
```

In another terminal:

```
ps -eo pid,stat,command | grep ping | grep -v grep
12518 S+   ping 8.8.8.8
```

Which informs us:

- the PID is `12518`
- the process **state** is `S+` (via keyword `stat`)
- the `command` that spawned the process was `ping 8.8.8.8`

There is one more step required to learn if this process if foreground or background: The **state** value of `S+` must be *decoded* in `man ps` under the heading of `PROCESS STATE CODE` - which tells us:

> S interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
> + is in the foreground process group

Consequently, we see from the `+` in the second character position that this process is running in the **foreground**. A background process may be listed with an `S` in the first character position, and nothing in the second position. There are several other character combinations that indicate a background process; see [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-what-processes-are-running-in-the-background-on-linux/) for a listing.

---

***FWIW:*** This works on my Debian-based system (reported as version `ps from procps-ng 3.3.15`), and in macOS 10.15 (which is descended from the BSD version of `ps`).